# Can't print google's vision API results to app screen

Tags: swift, swifty-json, google-vision

I'm using Google's Vision API to identify certain features in an image. I have the Logo Detection working as the logo comes up in my terminal, but I can't get it to appear on my app screen. It continually prints "No logos found" - here's my code :

```
    //Get logo annotations
            let logoAnnotations: JSON = logoResponses["logoAnnotations"]
            let numLogos: Int = logoAnnotations.count
            var logos: Array<String> = []
            if numLogos > 0 {
                var allResultsText:String = "Logos: "
                for index in 0..<numLogos {
                    let logo = logoAnnotations[index]["logo"].stringValue
                    logos.append(logo)
                }
                for logo in logos {
                    if logos[logos.count - 1] != logo {
                        allResultsText += "\(logo), "
                    } else {
                        allResultsText += "\(logo)."
                    }
                }
                self.allResults.text = allResultsText
            } else {
                self.allResults.text = "No logos found"
            }
        }
```

This is the JSON response I'm getting:

```
[
  {
    "boundingPoly": {
      "vertices": [
        {
          "x": 210,
          "y": 139
        },
        {
          "x": 229,
          "y": 139
        },
        {
          "x": 229,
          "y": 179
        },
        {
          "x": 210,
          "y": 179
        }
      ]
    },
    "mid": "/m/04lg33",
    "score": 0.18314756,
    "description": "Ralph Lauren Corporation"
  }
]
```

How am I to access the value returned for the logo description, this case Ralph Lauren Corporation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected the issue in my code. Here is the functioning code for anyone that needs it:

```
 let logoAnnotations: JSON = responses["logoAnnotations"]
            let numLogos: Int = logoAnnotations.count
            var logos: Array<String> = []
            if numLogos > 0 {
                var logoResultsText:String = " ,"
                for index in 0..<numLogos {
                    let logo = logoAnnotations[index]["description"].stringValue
                    logos.append(logo)
                }
                for logo in logos {
                    if logos[logos.count - 1] != logo {
                        logoResultsText += ", \(logo), "
                    } else {
                        logoResultsText += "\(logo)."
                    }
                }
                self.logoResults.text = logoResultsText
            } else {
                self.logoResults.text = ""
            }
```

I was calling the incorrect index from the logoAnnotations array.